# What's the best method for automatically deleting users posts in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm creating an listings type of web application and would like users posts to automatically be deleted a certain time after there post/listing expires?

In more detail on the app you post, lets say a car-lift you will give someone to a destination. I want the post to delete itself 24 hours after the lift was done

Is cronjob/scheduler for rails the only way to do this? Isn't there an easier way?

I'm struggling to get my head around it.

Here is the code in: lib/tasks/scheduler.rake

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku scheduler add-on"


task :delete_hosting => :environment do
 => not sure what goes here, something like => User.host.after_time.delete? //
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resque-Scheduler is a perfect match for that functionality: https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler

```
Resque.enqueue_in(1.day, DeleteUserPost, :user_post_id => user_post.id)
```

And in DeleteUserPost you code the deletion of the UserPost